# Can we query child to parent record fields in a Lightning Flow in getRecordS

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-experience, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have requirement to get all contacts where account name is a particular value. How can i do it in GetRecord in Lightning Flow?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Flow does not support filtering by parent fields.
The easiest way to work around it would be to create a new formula field on Contact which will surface Account Name on Contact records and use that field in the filter.
Please note, that when *Contacts to Multiple Accounts* are enabled, only the primary Account name will be used.